Capture and print on the exact match from a file
I am trying to use grep to match only a specific part of a row in a file.
The file is a huge csv file with some columns containing json with commas so it is hard to figure out which column what I am looking for is.
I am using
egrep -o 'opened for client .*\(' filename.csv

and this gives me the full csv rows containing as part of the line the search term, the problem is that I am interested in either capturing the part matched in the .* or only list the search term and nothing else.
So if I have a row in the csv:
,,,,,opened for client jdoe (P) and details attached,,,,,,
,,,,,opened for client jjunior (P2) and details attached,,,,,,

the empty columns before after are filled with hundreds of other information. Omitting for clarity
I want to print only
I.e. either
opened for client jdoe  
opened for client jjunior  
etc  

or only
jdoe  
jjunior  

How can I do that?

So you want to match lines that contain the ( but you don't want to display that (or anything past it)?

Please [edit] your question and add an example input and the output you would want from that example. Describe how we can know what part it is that you want: do we want everything until the last ( on the line? Everything until the first (? Everything until the first space? How can we know what part you want?

That egrep -o 'opened for client .*(' should return an error because of that unmatched (.

@StéphaneChazelas: yes the backslash was not pasted. Updated post

So what do we want to find? The first what after the opened for client? Should we stop at the first space? Should we stop at the first (? Will there always be a (?

@terdon: eithere stop at first ( or the name prior to the first space

Replace your .* with [^(]*, which matches "anything except ( for as long as possible":
grep -o 'opened for client [^(]*' filename.csv

Or you could use a different tool and its standard POSIX functionality:
sed -En 's/^.*(opened for client [^(]*)\(.*/\1/p' filename.csv

Or since you're already using the non-standard -o flag you could go wild and use PCRE with lookahead to match something that isn't included in the result:
grep -oP 'opened for client .*(?=\()' filename.csv

Note that all of these will include any whitespace you may have immediately preceding your terminating ( character. Don't forget to omit this too if you don't want/need it. For example,
grep -oP 'opened for client .*?(?=\s*\()' filename.csv


With pcregrep or pcre2grep, you can use -o1 to output what was matched by the 1st group:
pcre2grep -o1 'opened for client (.*?) \('

If your grep supports the non-standard -o, then maybe it also supports -P:
grep -Po 'opened for client \K.*?(?= \()'

Or use perl directly (the first p in pcre2grep or the P in -P):
perl -lne 'print $1 while /opened for client (.*?) \(/g'

If there's only one occurrence per line and the input is valid text in the user's locale, standardly, you can use sed:
sed -n 's/.*opened for client \([^(]*\) (.*/\1/p'

The output will be different though for inputs like opened for client foo(bar) (P2)
